# Most efficient way to get the integer index of a key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the integer location of a key to a pandas index as quickly as possible?

eg, given `pd.DataFrame(data=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), index=['alice', 'bob', 'charlie'])`

what is the fastest way to go from 'bob' to 1

Comment: Provide a sample dataframe and a required output to make your question clearer.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055530/is-searchsorted-faster-than-get-loc-to-find-label-location-in-a-dataframe-index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html), it was made for this purpose!

```
df.index.get_loc('bob')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the fastest but you can use [index.get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), index=['alice', 'bob', 'charlie'])

print(df.index.get_loc("bob"))
1
```