# Is searchsorted faster than get_loc to find label location in a DataFrame Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the integer location for a label in a Pandas index. I know I can use get_loc method, but then I discovered searchsorted. Just wondering if I should use the latter for speed improvement, as I need to search for thousands of labels.

Comment: Will you need get_loc's method or tolerance parameters? If not, np.searchsorted is more general so it should be faster.

Comment: I don't need tolerance, only exact matches. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on your usecase. using @ayhan's example.

With `get_loc` there is a big upfront cost of creating the hash table on the first lookup.

```
In [22]: idx = pd.Index(['R{0:07d}'.format(i) for i in range(10**7)])
In [23]: to_search = np.random.choice(idx, 10**5, replace=False)
In [24]: %time idx.get_loc(to_search[0])
Wall time: 1.57 s
```

But, subsequent lookups may be faster. (not guaranteed, depends on data)

```
In [9]: %%time
   ...: for i in to_search:
   ...:     idx.get_loc(i)
Wall time: 200 ms

In [10]: %%time
    ...: for i in to_search:
    ...:     np.searchsorted(idx, i)
Wall time: 486 ms
```

Also, as Jeff noted, `get_loc` is guaranteed to always work, where `searchsorted` requires monotonicity (and doesn't check).

Comment: amazing, so many details to keep into consideration. Thank you!