# What is the time complexity of .at and .loc in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm looking for the time complexity of these methods as a function of the number of rows in a dataframe, n.

Another way of asking this question is: Are indexes for dataframes in pandas btrees (with log(n) time look ups) or hash tables (with constant time lookups)?

Asking this question because I'd like a way to do constant time look ups for rows in a dataframe based on a custom index.

Answer (score 5):

Alright so it would appear that:

1) You can build your own index on a dataframe with .set_index **in O(n) time** where n is the number of rows in the dataframe

2) The index is lazily initialized and built (in O(n) time) the first time you try to access a row using that index. So accessing a row for the first time using that index takes O(n) time

3) All **subsequent row access takes constant time**.

So it looks like the indexes are hash tables and not btrees.

Comment: "The index is lazily initialized and built (in O(n) time) the first time you try to access a row using that index." Is it? Do you have a link to docs saying this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wes [here](https://www.slideshare.net/wesm/a-look-at-pandas-design-and-development) makes a few references to khash from klib which I believe they use for the indices.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No. Hence the preface "It would appear that". If I were able to find documentation on this I wouldn't have asked the question :)

Comment: I would also be curious about the specific behavior you are seeing that makes it appear that way. There isn't a lot of laziness in `pandas` so I'm just curious. And granted, you are asking a question but you are also posting an answer :)

Comment: Accessing the first row in a dataframe with ~10M rows using the custom index I built took ~3 seconds. Everything after that took milliseconds. Witnessed this behavior a few separate times. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39055999/2285236) another related post.

Comment: Interesting, any details you can add to your answer I think are valuable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245331/11262633 to this question.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Pandas Internals documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/internals.html), the default DataFrame index

> Populates a dict of label to location in Cython to do O(1) lookups.

`dict` uses [hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605279/how-do-python-dictionary-hash-lookups-work), supporting Peter Berg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58882586/11262633) to this question.